# Signup method throw null pointer Exception in my controller class

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I want to create users in my database with the `UserService` class. For that, I check if the user email s not present with the findByUserEmail  method . I use `Optional` in order to face the `NullpointerException` problem. The purpose of the `signup` method is to create a new user in the database if the provided email was not found in the database.I just removed the rest of the methods in the userService class leaving only the problematic one which is the findUserByEmail method. And the ComanLineRuner interface was used to add users to the database. I would like to know why this method that I use does not work.

**this UserService implementation class:**

```java
@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper,
            BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        super();
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
        this.passwordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDto findUserByEmail(String email) {

        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);

        if (user.isPresent()) {
            log.debug("findUserByEmail:{}", user.get());
            return UserMapper.userToUserDto(user.get());
        }

        throw exception(EntityType.USER, ExceptionType.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND, "User with this: " + email + "Not found");

    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public UserDto signup(UserDto userDto) {

        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(userDto.getEmail());

        Role userRole = new Role();
        if (user.isPresent()) {

            if (userDto.isAdmin()) {

                userRole = roleRepository.findRoleByUserRoleName(UserRole.ADMIN);
                
            } else {
                userRole = roleRepository.findRoleByUserRoleName(UserRole.STUDENT);
                
            }

            user = Optional.ofNullable(new User().setEmail(userDto.getEmail()).setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName())
                    .setLastName(userDto.getLastName()).setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()))
                    .setRoles(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(userRole))).setMobileNumber(userDto.getMobileNumber()));
            log.debug("signup new user:{}", UserMapper.userToUserDto(userRepository.save(user.get())));
            return UserMapper.userToUserDto(userRepository.save(user.get()));
        }
        throw exception(EntityType.USER, ExceptionType.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND, userDto.getEmail());
    }
}
```

**the user  class is:**

```java
public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, updatable = true)
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    

    @Column(name = "mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName != null ? firstName.concat(" ").concat(lastName) : "";
    }
}
```

**the user Dto class is:**

```java
public class UserDto {

    private String email;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String password;

    private boolean isAdmin;

    private String mobileNumber;
    
    private Set<RoleDto> roleDtos = new HashSet<>();
    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName != null ? firstName.concat(" ").concat(lastName) : "";
    }
}
```

**and my controller class is:**

```java
public class AdminController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/signup")
    public ModelAndView signup() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("signup");
        modelAndView.addObject("adminSignupCommand", new AdminSignupCommand());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    /**
     * @param adminSignupCommand
     * @param bindingResult
     * @param redirectAttributes
     * @return modelAndView
     */

    @PostMapping(value = "/signup")
    public ModelAndView creatnewUserAdmin(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("adminSignupCommand") AdminSignupCommand adminSignupCommand,
            BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
         

      // *Check user email in database before to save it*

        UserDto userDto = userService.findUserByEmail(adminSignupCommand.getEmail());
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("signup");

        if (userDto !=null) {

            bindingResult.reject("There is already a user registered with the email provided");
            log.debug("There is already a user registered with the email provided");
        }

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

            return modelAndView;
        } else {

            registerUserAdmin(adminSignupCommand);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "SuccesFully added the new user with admin role");
            modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", redirectAttributes);
            log.debug(" A user registered with the email provided");
        }
        return  new ModelAndView("login");
    }

    
    /**
     * @param adminSignupCommand
     * @return userDto
     */
    private UserDto registerUserAdmin(@Valid AdminSignupCommand adminSignupCommand) {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto().setEmail(adminSignupCommand.getEmail())
                .setFirstName(adminSignupCommand.getFirstName()).setLastName(adminSignupCommand.getLastName())
                .setPassword(adminSignupCommand.getPassword()).setAdmin(true);
        UserDto userDto2 = userService.signup(userDto);
        return userDto2;

    }

}

*CommandLineRunner*

    public class KalanblowApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KalanblowApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner addNewRole(RoleRepository roleRepository, UserRepository userRepository,
            UserService userService) {
        return (args) -> {
            log.debug("CommandLineRunner start");

            // create role in database
            Role adminRole = roleRepository.findRoleByUserRoleName(UserRole.ADMIN);

            

            // Create new User with role

            UserDto adminDto = userService.findUserByEmail("admin3@example.com");

            if (adminDto ==null) {
                adminDto = new UserDto();

                adminDto.setEmail("admin3@example.com");
                adminDto.setFirstName("admin3");
                adminDto.setLastName("admin3");
                adminDto.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("Example2021!"));
                adminDto.setMobileNumber("0256369645");
                adminDto.setRoleDtos(new HashSet<>(Arrays
                        .asList(new ModelMapper().map(adminRole, RoleDto.class))));
                
                System.out.println("adminDto is:" + adminDto);
                userService.signup(adminDto);
            } 
        };
    }
}
```

```
StackTrace return a java.lang.NullPonterException when saving Spring Entity
 **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:794) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at ml.kalanblowSystemManagement.KalanblowApplication.main(KalanblowApplication.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at ml.kalanblowSystemManagement.exception.KalanblowSystemManagementException.format(KalanblowSystemManagementException.java:92) ~[classes/:na]
    at ml.kalanblowSystemManagement.exception.KalanblowSystemManagementException.throwException(KalanblowSystemManagementException.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
    at ml.kalanblowSystemManagement.exception.KalanblowSystemManagementException.throwException(KalanblowSystemManagementException.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at ml.kalanblowSystemManagement.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.exception(UserServiceImpl.java:286) ~[classes/:na]
    at ****ml.kalanblowSystemManagement.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.findUserByEmail(UserServiceImpl.java:86) ~[classes/:na]****
    at ml.kalanblowSystemManagement.service.impl.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d9d5886b.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at ml.kalanblowSystemManagement.service.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aac12850.findUserByEmail(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at ml.kalanblowSystemManagement.KalanblowApplication.lambda$0(KalanblowApplication.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:791) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    ... 10 common frames omitted**
```

Comment: Generally when you are using optional with `isPresent` you are doing things the wrong way. Also we must guess what line 86 is in your code? Note this has nothing to do with your controller but everything with startup code you wrote (a `CommandLIneRunner`.

Comment: The line 86 corresponds to throw exception(EntityType.USER, ExceptionType.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND, "User with this: " + email + "Not found");, is nothing else than the exception that is triggered by the method.Sorry, I just added the CommandLinerRuner

Comment: Which is a method call, which does what?

Comment: findUserByemail throw null pointer exception if email is not found is the cause of exception

Answer (score 0):

There are some lacks on your methods architecture.

First of all, the `findUserByEmail` method always raises an `Exception` if no `User` has been found.

Your `Exception` seems to extend a `NullPointerException`, I would consider to use a custom exception instead.

So when you call the `findUserByEmail` method, and the `User` does not exist, an Exception will always be raised. Assuming that you want to keep the exception raising, you need to catch the Exception every time you call the method, in order to apply a mitigation of the error.
For example, your `CommandLineRunner` could be:

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner addNewRole(RoleRepository roleRepository, UserRepository userRepository,
        UserService userService) {
    return (args) -> {
        log.debug("CommandLineRunner start");

        // create role in database
        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findRoleByUserRoleName(UserRole.ADMIN);     

        // Create new User with role
        UserDto adminDto = null;
        
        try {
            adminDto = userService.findUserByEmail("admin3@example.com");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            adminDto = null;
        }       

        if (adminDto ==null) {
            adminDto = new UserDto();

            adminDto.setEmail("admin3@example.com");
            adminDto.setFirstName("admin3");
            adminDto.setLastName("admin3");
            adminDto.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("Example2021!"));
            adminDto.setMobileNumber("0256369645");
            adminDto.setRoleDtos(new HashSet<>(Arrays
                    .asList(new ModelMapper().map(adminRole, RoleDto.class))));
            
            System.out.println("adminDto is:" + adminDto);
            userService.signup(adminDto);
        } 
    };
}
```

I would rather suggest to do not raise an *Exception* on your `findUserByEmail` method. Use `Optional<UserDto>` instead, in order to keep your flow clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right, but I solved the problem by adding a boolean method emailExist(String email) in which I called the method  findUserByEmail. Thanks to all of you for your advice and feedback.
`public boolean emailExist(String email) {

```
    return userRepository.findUserByEmail(email) != null;
}
```

> So I modified the signup method

```
@Override
@SneakyThrows
public UserDto signup(UserDto userDto) {

    if (!emailExist(userDto.getEmail())) {

        throw exception(EntityType.USER, ExceptionType.DUPLICATE_ENTITY,
                "An user with that email adress already exists:" + userDto.getEmail());
    }
    Role userRole = new Role();

    if (userDto.isAdmin()) {
        userRole = roleRepository.findRoleByUserRoleName(UserRole.ADMIN);
    } else {
        userRole = roleRepository.findRoleByUserRoleName(UserRole.STUDENT);
    }
    User user = new User().setBirthDate(userDto.getBirthDate()).setEmail(userDto.getEmail())
            .setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName()).setLastName(userDto.getLastName())
            .setMatchingPassword(userDto.getMatchingPassword()).setPassword(userDto.getPassword())
            .setMobileNumber(userDto.getMobileNumber()).setRoles(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));

    return UserMapper.userToUserDto(userRepository.save(user));
}
```